# Select from database without duplicate

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to develop php page but I have a problem, I would like to get data from data base without duplicate.

```
$tsql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FactoriesViolations";
$rowsPerPage = 25;
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
```

please help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `$tsql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM FactoriesViolations";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what all columns are you expecting in your output. If its only ID

```
 $tsql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM FactoriesViolations";
```

if you want all the columns from the table and eliminate the duplicate records
this query will do the needful.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2,... ColN FROM FactoriesViolations GROUP BY Col1, Col2,... ColN;
```

here Col1, Col2,... ColN are column names of your FactoriesViolations  table.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query. It will work.

```
$tsql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM FactoriesViolations";
```

Answer (score 1):

use below way for count of unique records

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM FactoriesViolations;  // column_name is column which contains duplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

**DISTINCT** keyword tells the server to go through the whole result set and remove all duplicate rows after the query has been performed.

Format :

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CONDITION(S)
```

In your case, the following query should work

```
$tsql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM FactoriesViolations" ;
```

This will return the count of all unique IDs existing in the table.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. And `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron.

Comment: I never said it's a function. I said it's a keyword which eliminates duplicate records.

Comment: You included parentheses, implying that '*' (or ID) was an argument of DISTINCT.